# Django: Equivalent of "select [column name] from [tablename]"

Tags: django, django-models

I wanted to know is there anything equivalent to:

```
select columnname from tablename
```

Like Django tutorial says:

```
Entry.objects.filter(condition)
```

fetches all the objects with the given condition. It is like:

```
select * from Entry where condition
```

But I want to make a list of only one column [which in my case is a foreign key]. Found that:

```
Entry.objects.values_list('column_name', flat=True).filter(condition)
```

does the same. But in my case the column is a foreign key, and this query loses the property of a foreign key. It's just storing the values. I am not able to make the look-up calls.

Comment: I started to write an answer, and now I'm not sure. Do you want django to return an object from the foreign key, or do you want the key itself?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Of course, `values` and `values_list` will retrieve the raw values from the database. Django can't work its "magic" on a model which means you don't get to traverse relationships because you're stuck with the id the foreign key is pointing towards, rather than the ForeignKey field.

If you need to filters those values, you could do the following (assuming `column_name` is a ForeignKey pointing to `MyModel`):

```
ids = Entry.objects.values_list('column_name', flat=True).filter(...)
my_models = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=set(ids))
```

Here's a documentation for [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Comment: this may work but if it were me I world not be happy about having to make two calls to the database. @Gareth Rees has a better approach -- flip the query around and write it from the perspective of the object you want and take advantage of the related_name

Comment: how to specify all columns?

Answer (score 13):

To restrict a query set to a specific column(s) you use .values(columname)

You should also probably add distinct to the end, so your query will end being:

```
Entry.objects.filter(myfilter).values(columname).distinct()
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

for more information

Depending on your answer in the comment, I'll come back and edit.

Edit:

I'm not certain if the approach is right one though. You can get all of your objects in a python list by getting a normal queryset via filter and then doing:

```
myobjectlist = map(lambda x: x.mycolumnname, myqueryset)
```

The only problem with that approach is if your queryset is large your memory use is going to be equally large.

Anyway, I'm still not certain on some of the specifics of the problem.

Comment: values() is giving similar results to values_list(). I am getting the 'user' column values as 1L, 2L... but the foreign key relationship is lost. I am unable to access the 'user' class.

Comment: a similar, equally non-elegant solution for getting the items instead of ID's is:

[instance.member for instance in Entry.filter(condition).distinct('member')]

Answer (score 10):

You have a model `A` with a foreign key to another model `B`, and you want to select the `B`s which are referred to by some `A`. Is that right? If so, the query you want is just:

```
B.objects.filter(a__isnull = False)
```

If you have conditions on the corresponding `A`, then the query can be:

```
B.objects.filter(a__field1 = value1, a__field2 = value2, ...)
```

See [Django's backwards relation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) for an explanation of why this works, and the [`ForeignKey.related_name` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) if you want to change the name of the backwards relation.

Comment: I think this is the better approach but you should probably mention using the related_name